# DB Scheme tables

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform

I am a DB newbie, and i am working on my apps DB scheme, and i came into a wall in representing one of the tables.
I am working with parse DB as a starter DB until i get the app rolling.
In the parse DB i have a TV show Entity, Episode Entity (one to many relationship) and a user Entity. I have entered a few TV-Shows into the Parse DB.
I want to be able to follow the episodes the user has viewed.
Until now i have created a array of Episodes that the user have viewed and when i want to get them all i just fetch them, but it seems a bit tedious and inefficient.

My Q is, is there any way else to represent the relationship between the viewed Episodes to the user.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new table called `WatchedEpisodes`. This table will contain two pointers. The first pointer will be a `UserPointer` and the second will be an `EpisodePointer`. Then you can run the following code to get all the episodes that the currentUser has watched.

**Swift**

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "WatchedEpisodes")
query.whereKey("UserPointer", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
query.find({
    //Handle success and error
});
```